# How to detect Monitor Resolution in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

How to detect the Monitor current resolution in flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`flash.system.Capabilities` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) and its properties `screenDPI`, `screenResolutionX` and `screenResolutionY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just detect screen resolution in Flex.  The closest thing you can do is switch to full screen mode and then check your stage resolution, which will then equal monitor resolution.

To switch to full screen set the stage's `displayState` property to `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`.